# landscape orientation in ereaders: css for both 1 and 2 page layout?

Tags: css, apple-books, media-queries

I'm trying to write css media queries for landscape and portrait orientations.

With widths of 1024 pix and wider, you think that 1024 pixels is enough to have 2 columns instead of 1.

But does any ebook software allow  the user to specify single page layout or double page layout for landscape orientation? If yes, how do you use conditional CSS media queries to specify  when there is only 1 column as opposed to 2? For example, do later versions of ibooks with the retina display let you set one column and two column mode for landscape orientation?

**Update:** I see the Kindle app for Android lets you specify 1 or 2 columns for landscape orientation. Gitden on Android does the same. ibooks 3.13 (for ipad 1) has no option; it just shows 2 columns by default for landscape.

When processing the media query for a 1024 px image, does it consider the pixel width for each page to be 512? Or does it consider the width of a 2 column page to be the combined total (512+512)?

Comment: I think that rather than the screen resolution, you should consider the screen size. Some android apps could have a two-page layout, but generally a tablet has a larger screen than an ereader; I think that the 6 inch display of a standard ereader is too small to be splitted in two and still be easily readable.

Comment: My fear is that a css media query for a landscape layout of 1200 would not be appropriate  when the landscape layout consists of 2 pages of 600 pixels each...